# WordPress redirect after successful form validation and submit

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, redirect

I have a custom page template with a form in `page-report.php`.

I do validation on it, so I need the action to lead to the same form, but I need to redirect to a different page on successful validation.

`wp_redirect()` is not working, because is spitting out the `header()` function after the output was started already.

```
if($_POST['report'])
{
    if($validator->ValidateForm())
    {
        wp_redirect('http://thankyou') // redirect
    }
}
```

I cannot use `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` because the header is not included in this page template.

I tried to put a function in `functions.php` :

```
add_action('get_header','redirect_to');
function redirect_to($page){
    if($page)
    {   
        wp_redirect('http://www.google.com');
    }
}
```

But that works only if I don't have the conditional `if()`.

If I use it, the `wp_redirect()` is being spat out after the output was started.

What is my best approach to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...
Since I was doing everything from inside an admin page, the header was fired up before the wp_redirect() as it was explained in the question.

So I ended up making a new function at the top:

```
add_action('admin_init','redirect_to');
function redirect_to()
{
        if ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'adduser' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
                    wp_redirect($redirect);
                    die();
                }
        }

}
```

That is making sure that the redirect_to() function will be fired up before the header (on admin_init). Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works perfect.

Comment: What is `$redirect`? You've not defined it

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the save_post hook:

do_action('save_post', 'custom_add_save');

```
function custom_add_save($postID){
// called after a post or page is saved
    if($_POST['report']) {

      if($validator->ValidateForm())
           {
                wp_redirect('http://thankyou') // redirect
           }

    }
```

Also you could just try using a plugin instead of your own code...Gravity Forms and Contact form 7 both work well.

}

Comment: I cannot use the 'save_post', but you are right about the do_action(). I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( $_POST['report'] ) {

    if( $validator->ValidateForm() ) {
        header( 'Location: http://thankyou' ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - it doesn't work. wp_redirect() is using header() too. The problem is that the header() needs to happen before anything else is displayed on the page, and this is why it is failing...

Answer (score 0):

So in the case anybody is looking for "Redirect after post" in wordpress, this is how you do it:

```
wp_redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: This will fail if your form action is `admin-post.php`